# Python class - storing and referring back to the instances

Tags: python, class, instance

I'm trying to make a class that has: namespace, filepath and selectionset data (list) data contained within it.

I have a UI that will allow me to add a new 'record' for each character I input.

So far I've got this:

```
mainlist = []

class chRecord:
    def __init__(self, namespace, filepath, selSets =[]):
        self.namespace = namespace
        self.filepath = filepath
        self.selSets = selSets


aName = "John:"
aAge = "C:/temp/"
aSelSets = "Animation:stuff_Junk 0-10, 
animation:bob_jeff 10-30"

characterRecord = chRecord(aName,aAge,aSelSets)

mainlist.append(characterRecord)

aName = "John2:"
aAge = "C:/temp/"
aSelSets = "Animation:stuff_Junk2 0-10, 
animation:bob_jeff2 10-30"

characterRecord = chRecord(aName,aAge,aSelSets)

mainlist.append(characterRecord)
```

My problem is how do I then search `mainList` to find the record I'm after.  I.e. 'John' and then find the namespace, filepath and selectionset data?

Sorry if my terminology is wrong on some of this!

Cheers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you needed to force unique values you could use a dictionary. Just set the key to a unique value or a value that should be unique.

This should run faster than looping, but will override data if the keys aren't unique.

```
mainlist = {}

class chRecord:
    def __init__(self, namespace, filepath, selSets =[]):
        self.namespace = namespace
        self.filepath = filepath
        self.selSets = selSets


aName = "John:"
aAge = "C:/temp/"
aSelSets = "Animation:stuff_Junk 0-10, animation:bob_jeff 10-30"

mainlist[aName] = chRecord(aName,aAge,aSelSets)
print(mainlist[aName].selSets)

aName = "John2:"
aAge = "C:/temp/"
aSelSets = "Animation:stuff_Junk2 0-10, animation:bob_jeff2 10-30"

mainlist[aName] = chRecord(aName,aAge,aSelSets)

print(mainlist.get('John2:').namespace)
print(mainlist.get('John2:').filepath)
print(mainlist.get('John2:').selSets)
```

Comment: Thank you for that example.   This sounds like it will be quite useful using a dict.  Overriding the records isn't much of an issue as i want the ability to update / delete existing records.

Answer (score 1):

While it's commonly used as a full-blown website framework, a [Django model](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/db/models/) aligns pretty closely with what you're trying to do here regarding filtering:

```
from django.db import models


class CHRecord(models.Model):
    namespace = models.CharField(max_length=32)
    filepath = models.FileField()
    # Not sure what this represents in your question, but if you use
    # PostgreSQL as your backend, might want an Array
    sel_sets = models.CharField(max_length=512)

# Saves a row to a database (local SQLite by default)
CHRecord.objects.create(namespace="John:", filepath="C:/temp/", sel_sets="xyz")

# Get matching rows translating to a SQL query
CHRecord.objects.filter(namespace__contains="John")
```

Comment: Cool, thank you.  That looks like it would do what i want it to.  I'm using motionbuilder python to create this tool, so I assume it will allow me to import the django.db.

Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

You would need to create a function that takes as argument a list of records and searches by name. It will then return the matched record and you will be able to get the additional information from it.

**Example:**

```
mainlist = []


def find_record_by_name(records, name):
    for record in records:

        if record.namespace == name:
            return record


class chRecord:
    def __init__(self, namespace, filepath, selSets=[]):
        self.namespace = namespace
        self.filepath = filepath
        self.selSets = selSets


aName = "John:"
aAge = "C:/temp/"
aSelSets = "Animation:stuff_Junk 0-10, animation:bob_jeff 10-30"

characterRecord = chRecord(aName, aAge, aSelSets)

mainlist.append(characterRecord)

aName = "John2:"
aAge = "C:/temp/"
aSelSets = "Animation:stuff_Junk2 0-10,animation:bob_jeff2 10-30"

characterRecord = chRecord(aName, aAge, aSelSets)

mainlist.append(characterRecord)

selected_record = find_record_by_name(mainlist, "John:")

if selected_record:
    print(selected_record.namespace)
    print(selected_record.filepath)
    print(selected_record.selSets)
```

Comment: Awesome!  That function is perfect!

Can't thank you enough!  I'm pretty new to python in general & I was having trouble visualizing what was happening with the record data.

Cheers.

Comment: I'll have to wait until Monday to fully test it, but i'm confident that it'll do the trick.
I'm happy to upvote :-)

Comment: Ok one last question....as the (selected_record.selSets) bit is a list of items, is there anything special I have to do to get access to them?  I intend to be able to delete / add / edit existing etc.

Comment: You should be able to access it as a normal list. e.g `selected_record.selSets[0]` will give you the first element and `selected_record.selSets.append('some_new_value')` will append to the list

Answer (score 0):

Go through the list and match on the `namespace` attribute.

```
for record in mainlist:
    if record.namespace == 'John':
        # the record is found, now you can access the attributes with `record.filepath`
        print(record)
```

Comment: Right!  I see, I've been going about it a bit backwards it seems.  I was faffing around with getting indexes like a n00b!

Thank you, that makes sense.